# Check if Calendar (List) is free in SharePoint CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, csom

I am writing javascript (CSOM) code in SharePoint to add items to SharePoint Calendar app (list).

I want to add these records only if calendar is free during the specified time.

i.e in below ex, I want to check if calendar is free from 08:00 to 08:15 before adding

```
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(); 
    var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    var startdate = new Date('2017-10-21 08:00 GMT+0000').toISOString();
    var enddate = new Date('2017-10-21 08:15 GMT+0000').toISOString();
    listItem.set_item("Title", "My Event");
    listItem.set_item("EventDate", startdate);
    listItem.set_item("EndDate", enddate);
    listItem.set_item("Location", "MyCalander");            
    listItem.update();
```

Comment: are you getting errors? Are you having issues receiving the data from the list? You've given what you want, but what is the issue and what have you tried?

Comment: i want to create record only if calender is free on mentioned time (eg 08:00 to 08:15)

Comment: The calendar is just a list behind a view. I would query the calendar event list and filter for events that start before/at your desired start time and end after/at your desired end time. If you get any results then you know there is something scheduled. Otherwise schedule your event

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query you can use: (The caml value looks terrible so I'll post the xml below)

```
function queryCalendar(startDate, endDate) {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Calendar");
    var caml = "\n<View>\n    <Query>\n        <Where>\n            <And>\n                <Lt>\n                    <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />\n                    <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True' StorageTZ='TRUE'>" + endDate.toISOString() + "</Value>\n                </Lt>\n                <Gt>\n                    <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />\n                    <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True' StorageTZ='TRUE'>" + startDate.toISOString() + "</Value>\n                </Gt>\n            </And>\n        </Where>\n    </Query>\n    <ViewFields>\n        <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />\n        <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />\n        <FieldRef Name='Title' />\n    </ViewFields>\n</View>\n\n";
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml(caml);
    var listItems = list.getItems(query);
    context.load(listItems);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
        if (listItems.get_count() > 0) {
            console.warn("That time is already booked");
        }
        else {
            console.log("that time is good");
        }
    }, function (sender, args) {
        console.error(args.get_message());
    });
}
```

Here is how I am calling it:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    queryCalendar(new Date(2019, 4, 27, 8), new Date(2019, 4, 27, 9));
}, "SP.js");
```

I use the following XML for the CAML:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Lt>
                    <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
                    <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue="True" StorageTZ='TRUE'>enddate</Value>
                </Lt>
                <Gt>
                    <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
                    <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue="True" StorageTZ='TRUE'>starttime</Value>
                </Gt>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
        <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
    </ViewFields>
</View>
```

Make sure to replace "enddate" and "startdate" with a proper date value and use date.toISOString() method (which might not work in IE).